# SAP B1 Query problem Linking OPDN, PDN1 (goods receipt) with Batch Report

Tags: sql, sapb1

I have a query problem with SAP Business One, we have a current report that we want to use for our customers that should pull all goods receipt for a customer and add the batch data to the report.

The current report looks like this:

```
SELECT T5.[DocNum], T5.[DocDate], T0.[ItemCode], T0.[Dscription], T4.[FrgnName], T4.[U_Customercode], T0.[Quantity], T3.[DISTNUMBER], T3.[Notes]
FROM DBO.OPDN T5 INNER JOIN DBO.PDN1 AS T0 ON T5.DOCENTRY=T0.DOCENTRY 
INNER JOIN
DBO.OILM AS T1 ON T1.DOCENTRY = T0.DOCENTRY AND T0.OBJTYPE = T1.TRANSTYPE AND T0.LINENUM = T1.DOCLINENUM 
INNER JOIN
DBO.ILM1 AS T2 ON T1.MESSAGEID = T2.MESSAGEID 
INNER JOIN
DBO.OBTN AS T3 ON T2.ITEMCODE = T3.ITEMCODE AND T2.SYSNUMBER = T3.SYSNUMBER 
INNER JOIN
DBO.OITM AS T4 ON T2.ITEMCODE = T4.ITEMCODE
WHERE T5.[CardCode] = XXXX AND  T5.[DocDate] >=[%0] AND  T5.[DocDate] <=[%19]
```

The problem I have, is that if I run this report it will pull the full quantity for that goods receipt for each batch number and not the quantity for just that batch.

I have tried linking this report with the `IBT1` table but then it will pull the quantity for just a random transaction in SAP B1.

This one looked like this:

```
SELECT T5.[DocNum], T5.[DocDate], T0.[ItemCode], T0.[Dscription], T4.[FrgnName], T4.[U_Customercode], T6.[Quantity], T3.[DISTNUMBER], T3.[Notes]
FROM DBO.OPDN T5 INNER JOIN DBO.PDN1 AS T0 ON T5.DOCENTRY=T0.DOCENTRY 
INNER JOIN
DBO.OILM AS T1 ON T1.DOCENTRY = T0.DOCENTRY AND T0.OBJTYPE = T1.TRANSTYPE AND T0.LINENUM = T1.DOCLINENUM 
INNER JOIN
DBO.ILM1 AS T2 ON T1.MESSAGEID = T2.MESSAGEID 
INNER JOIN
DBO.OBTN AS T3 ON T2.ITEMCODE = T3.ITEMCODE AND T2.SYSNUMBER = T3.SYSNUMBER 
INNER JOIN
DBO.OITM AS T4 ON T2.ITEMCODE = T4.ITEMCODE
INNER JOIN
DBO.IBT1 AS T6 ON T6.BatchNum = Cast(T3.SYSNUMBER as nvarchar(20))

WHERE T5.[CardCode] = XXXX AND  T5.[DocDate] >=[%0] AND  T5.[DocDate] <=[%19]
```

Can any of you help me, as I have already tried figuring it out but everything I do either gives me the incorrect data or just gives me error when I try and run the report.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a tip,. chose table aliases that make sense. T1, T2 etc just make it harder to read the code.

Comment: Is it SQL of MS SQL Server?

Comment: This is from the Query generator from SAP B1 that uses SQL.

Comment: I think you're looking for ILM1.Quantity

Comment: Thanks for that Table, i didnt notice i had that one already in the report and it seems to be pulling the correct quantity